# Breaking down contract transaction fees from logs

Tags: tokens, erc-20, fees

Looking at random transaction [like this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf68e82e878ab3517625fc3f5cab4a7e6fa31c08739d7f2f686cf76a922ca43dc) how can one tell home much fee each of the  involved participants paid? There is transaction fee that you pay from your wallet but here the fee is shared between multiple spenders.

Say the first one in the log [0x4d25634945b207a67282aa0b213e6f4f44ee36c3](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4d25634945b207a67282aa0b213e6f4f44ee36c3) to [0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631](https://etherscan.io/address/0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631), how does one know how much 0x4d25634945b207a67282aa0b213e6f4f44ee36c3 paid for this trnansaction?

Answer (score 0):

all the fees are paid by the `from` address of the transaction, in this case `0x4d25634945b207a67282aa0b213e6f4f44ee36c3`, . there's nothing as "multiple party sharing the fee"

Comment: So in the end nobody from the total of 7 From in the logs is paying anything except the transaction From address? I am asking because I want to log the fee from the logs for every From address. [Here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x755a2b0598eceadb89f703c18ad2fea8c1772c6b589606db80113149764a2951) looks clear who is paying the fee as the TX From and the only Transfer() From have the same address, I am just a bit confused when there are multiple (different) From in the logs. I am wondering if there is a case where multiple transfers from external addresses in logs where each From pays a fee.

Comment: Related to this who is the "real" sender (From) to each To that gets paid in the logs? The one from the TX From or the one from the topic From?